# How to convert GetFuncType using LINQBridge

Tags: linq, linqbridge

I have a client using .net and I am using LINQBride with some existing code that uses LINQ. I don't really know much about linq but am wondering if there is a quick conversion using LINQBridge for this expression

```
DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Expression.GetFuncType(typeof(IDataReader), type));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinqBridge only implements Linq to Objects, it doesn't support expressions. But you can achieve something similar using reflection:

```
static Type GetFuncType(params Type[] typeArgs)
{
    string typeName = "System.Func`" + typeArgs.Length;
    Type genericTypeDef = typeof(Func<>).Assembly.GetType(typeName); // Func<,...,>
    return genericTypeDef.MakeGenericType(typeArgs); // Func<TArg1, ..., TResult>
}
```